# ASP.Net core 2.2 deployment issue in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-2.2

I am new to .Net core environment and facing issue while deploying application into IIS.

After publishing code and deploying into IIS server(Version 7), I am able to start application from Kestrel by going into directory where application hosted and running below command.

c:\inetpub\demoapp\dotnet "My App.dll"

By running above command, Kestrel is running on http://localhost:5000 and I am able to browse from browser. **I am using latest .Net Core version 2.2.**

But when I am trying to execute URL from IIS hosted application, I am getting below error.

**HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure**

Below is the event log from windows application log.

***Application '/LM/W3SVC/49/ROOT/demoapp' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\demoapp\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\MyApp Web.dll' with multiple retries. The last try of listening port is '2405'. See previous warnings for details.***

Anyone having idea how to resolve it?

Comment: does 2405 port available for use?

Comment: please check this: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/616#issuecomment-369138733

Comment: Thank you Simonare! That port is changing everytime. Also tried out Git Hub link but no solution works for me unfortunately.

Comment: Open `web.config` and add quotes to your process name (as it contains space).

Comment: Hi Lex Li... Thank you for your reply... I tried to set web.config entry like below but doesn't work.

<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet.exe" arguments="'.\My App.dll'" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />

Comment: Is anyone has a way that I can try it out?

Comment: did exactly as Dharmesh did, same issue. anyone else have any idea?

Comment: turn out to be something else on the program.cs setup, fixed the db permission issue. now it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It was win-64 architect issue.

You can change or switch architect from win-64 to win-86 then publish and don't forget to change **Enable 32-bit Applications** in IIS manager:

- Right-click on the Application Pool and select “Advanced Settings…”
  or select the same from the Actions pane after selecting the
  Application pool.
- Change the “Enable 32-bit Applications” to True (if you want the
  application pool to spawn in a 32-bit mode)
     Click OK.

p.s.: Don't forget to delete existing published files.